# Install ambari on existing single node hadoop

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I have single node hadoop setup on Ubuntu(personal dev env.). 
 Now want to install Ambari.

Question: Can we install Ambari on existing hadoop set up if Yes than assist me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Ambari requires you first install Ambari agents, then Ambari server to monitor the agents + install / configure Hadoop.

In theory, if you installed Hadoop in the same way that Ambari expects, it might work, but adding any node into Ambari will throw lots of warnings if the node is running any extra process other than the agent